# An upper bound on the norm of the inverse of matrix A

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, upper-lower-bounds

please consider the following $n$-by-$n$ matrix:

$\\
A= \begin{bmatrix}
    0!      & 1! & 2! & \dots & n! \\
    -1!       & -2! & -3! & \dots & -(n+1)! \\
    2! & 3! & 4! & \dots& (n+2)! \\
    \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots  & \dots & \vdots \\
\ (-1)^n n!&(-1)^n (n+1)!&(-1)^n (n+2)! &\dots & (-1)^n (2n)!
\end{bmatrix}.$

I want to show that all the entries of $A^{-1}$ are bounded for finite values of $n$.

Can you help me?

My approach: I am seeking for an upper bound on the norm (1-norm preferably) of the inverse of matrix A.
I am aware of the following theorem:
$\Vert A^{-1}\Vert \le \frac{\Vert A \Vert ^{n-1}}{|det(A)|}$. However, following this strategy, I have to show that $det(A)$ is sufficiently far away from zero (I need a suitable lower bound for $det(A)$). I know that $A$ is non-singular, but it does not help.

Thanks.

Comment: You should reformulate *I want to show that all the entries of $A^{-1}$ are bounded for finite values of $n$* as for sure if the inverse exists, its values are finite and therefore bounded.

Comment: ... or do you want a uniform bound that works for all $n$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Thanks, so as far as I show $A$ is invertible, I am assured that all the entries of $A^{-1}$ are bounded, right?

Comment: @RobertIsrael If a uniform bound for any n exists, that would be best.

Comment: It looks to me like $$\det(A) = (-1)^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} k!^2$$

Comment: @RobertIsrael, Thank you Sir, can you give me a hint on the calculation of the determinant? I tried induction...

Comment: Just an empirical observation from computing the first $20$.

Comment: The magnitude of the largest entry in $A^{-1}$ does grow with $n$, apparently exponentially.  The first $20$ are $1, 2, 5, 14, 30, 55, 371/4, 203, 399, 723, 4917/4, 3971/2, 6149/2, 183755/36, 35139/4, 130819/9, 209219/9, 36091, 54587, 322677/4$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107761/discussion-between-mathisfreedom-and-robert-israel).